# How to send PDF file instead of text message (WhatsApp)

Tags: python

the code below for sending text messages but how to replace to attach PDF file and send it via WhatsApp
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, UnexpectedAlertPresentException, NoAlertPresentException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import quote
from sys import platform

```
options = Options()
if platform == "win64":
    options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

f = open("message.txt", "r")
message = f.read()
f.close()

print("##########################################################")
print('This is your message\n\n')
print(message)
print("##########################################################")
message = quote(message)

numbers = []
f = open("numbers.txt", "r")
for line in f.read().splitlines():
    if line != "":
        numbers.append(line)
f.close()
total_number=len(numbers)
print("##########################################################")
print('\nWe found ' + str(total_number) + ' numbers in the file')
print("##########################################################")
print()
delay = 30

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
print('Once your browser opens up sign in to web whatsapp')
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
input("Press ENTER after login into Whatsapp Web and your chats are visiable    .")
for idx, number in enumerate(numbers):
    number = number.strip()
    if number == "":
        continue
        print('{}/{} => Sending message to {}.'.format((idx+1), total_number, number))
    try:
        url = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + number + '&text=' + message
        sent = False
        for i in range(3):
            if not sent:
                driver.get(url)
                try:
                    click_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME , '_4sWnG')))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Something went wrong..\n Failed to send message to: {number}, retry ({i+1}/3)")
                    print("Make sure your phone and computer is connected to the internet.")
                    print("If there is an alert, please dismiss it.")
                    input("Press enter to continue")
                else:
                    sleep(1)
                    click_btn.click()
                    sent=True
                    sleep(3)
                    print('Message sent to: ' + number)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to send message to ' + number + str(e))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933480/how-to-send-media-files-on-whatsapp-programmatically-using-click-to-chat-feature

use the search functions I believe there are already some answers on your question